# Foreign keys in first normal form?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database for protein bars.
This is the conclusion I came to intuitively:

[image]

**But I also want to come to a conclusion by normalizing step-by-step:**
[image]

The dark gray background represents repeating groups.

**Question:**
In the last step when splitting the table into multiple new tables, do I add foreign keys? Or does adding foreign keys to the new tables happen in 2NF?

A prototype of the product can be found at [proteinbarinfo.com](https://proteinbarinfo.com)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding foreign key *constraints* happens anytime you create a dependent table. This can happen in any phase of normalization.

Adding numeric pseudokeys (`id`) to all your lookup tables isn't required for the sake of normalization. You can have strings as primary keys, and satisfy normal forms just as well.

It's appropriate when you have a many-to-many relationship, like between ProteinBars and Verified categories, to create a table in between with a composite key.

There's a mnemonic for the first three normal forms: Every column in a table must depend on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.

A table like `ProteinBar_has_Aroma` with a composite key and no other attributes implicitly satisfies all three conditions:

1. Since both columns are members of the primary key, they must depend on the primary key. That is, for a given primary key (i.e. a pair of specific values), you can obviously get both the protein bar and the aroma attributes.
2. The whole key - you need the whole primary key to find a given row, and therefore both columns in that table depend on the whole primary key.
3. Nothing but the key - there aren't any other (non-key) attribute columns to choose from, therefore they can't depend on anything but the key.

Comment: @user644361 & BillKarwin "Adding foreign key constraints happens anytime you create a dependent table. This can happen in any phase of normalization." "add" isn't defined but for this to be true it only applies to special cases. "dependent" isn't defined but once we produce a table that's not getting decomposed any more we are only guaranteed to "add" but not later "subtract" FKs it involves if we don't decompose the "determining" table or only decompose it in certain ways. The special & general cases aren't explained. (And memonics are not precise enough to reason with.) See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We determine FKs after we are done decomposing to a desired highest NF (normal form). (Note that decomposing to a target NF does not imply that we go through lower NFs. We use an appropriate algorithm.)

Every binary lossless decomposition introduces at least one FK (foreign key) from one component to another. (From any NF to any NFs. Whether or not any component is of a higher or lower NF than the original or the other.)

(Why? The components are projections of the original so they have the same values as it does in each column. Also (per a basic normalization theorem) a binary decomposition is lossless when/iff the common columns of the components are a superset of a CK (candidate key) of one of the tables. So there is at least a FK from a component to the other's CK. There might be more FKs.)

But if we go on to more decompositions to get only components that are in the target NF, those 2 components are not both in the final design, so neither are any FKs that held between them.

Moreover some lossless decompositions cannot be expressed by a combination of binary ones & might not introduce a FK. (Again, regardless of the NFs of the schemas.) These are decompositions for normalizing to above 4NF. (Contrary to common claims re 5NF, these are important desirable decompositions & the only reason they are not needed very often is that designs in violation are mostly so obviously bad that we don't consider them.)

So we have to determine FKs & other constraints on a final design. (If the last decomposition was binary, there will be at least one FK from it.)

PS Normalization to higher NFs does not introduce new column names, in particular ids. It replaces a relation schema by others that have proper subsets of its columns that join back to it.